# jQuery merge two id's into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have following HTML

```
<table id="sale_table_paging" class="display" style="width:100%">
<table id="purchase_table_paging" class="display" style="width:100%">
```

And this is the JQuery

```
    $('#sale_table_paging').DataTable();
    $('#purchase_table_paging').DataTable();
```

I'm trying to merge the `#sale_table_paging` and `#purchase_table_paging` but I'm not sure where to modify.

My expected result is something like

```
 <table id="global_table_paging" class="display" style="width:100%">
 <table id="global_table_paging" class="display" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: try with `$('table.display').DataTable()`

Comment: Your expected result is actually not valid since [`id` is supposed to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by merging id's? If you want to merge table data, you may check out my answer below.